# How to automate change value in a form when the button is clicked from javascript jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with 4 rows: `A`, `B`, `C`, and `Total`. 

The `C` is **optional**, so I can show/hide it. 

`Total` is the sum of `A` till `C`.

Let say I put A : 3, B : 4, and C : 7. So in Total, it will show 14. 

When I clicked **"Close C"**, it supposed to **sum** only `A` and `B` value, which is 7, `C` was **not** included even I already set the C value to 0. But it did not happen. Value in Total was still 14.

Here is my code so far

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_add_c").click(function()
  {
   $("#form_c").show();
   $("#add_value_c").hide();
  });
  
  $("#cancel_c_value").click(function()
  {
   $("#btn_add_c").show();
   $("#form_c").hide();
   //reset the value_c to 0
   $("#value_c").val(0);
  });
  
  $("#value_a, #value_b, #value_c").on("change", function()
  {
   var value_a = Math.abs($("#value_a").val());
   var value_b = Math.abs($("#value_b").val());
   var value_c = Math.abs($("#value_c").val());
   
   var total = value_a + value_b + value_c;
   
   $("#total").val(total);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <button type='button' id="btn_add_c">Add C</button>
</div>

<form action ="" method="post">
 <div>
   <label>Input A</label>
   <div>
     <input type="text" class="number" id="value_a">
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
   <label>Input B</label>
   <div>
    <input type="text" class="number" id="value_b">
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="form_c" style="display:none">
   <label>Input C</label>
   <div>
     <input type="text" class="number" id="value_c">
   </div>
   <i id="cancel_c_value">Close C</id>
 </div>
 
 <div>
   <label>Total</label>
   <div>
    <input type="text" class="number" id="total" readonly>
    </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Can anybody please help me how to change the Total value automatically when the close button was clicked.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3nrdyem/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value via Javascript won't result in a `change` event, but you can trigger one yourself with `$('#value_a').trigger('change');`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_add_c").click(function() {
    $("#form_c").show();
    $("#add_value_c").hide();
  });

  $("#cancel_c_value").click(function() {
    $("#btn_add_c").show();
    $("#form_c").hide();
    //reset the value_c to 0
    $("#value_c").val(0);
    $('#value_a').trigger('change');
  });

  $("#value_a, #value_b, #value_c").on("change", function() {
    var value_a = Math.abs($("#value_a").val());
    var value_b = Math.abs($("#value_b").val());
    var value_c = Math.abs($("#value_c").val());

    var total = value_a + value_b + value_c;

    $("#total").val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <button type='button' id="btn_add_c">Add C</button>
</div>

<form action ="" method="post">
 <div>
 <label>Input A</label>
 <div>
 <input type="text" class="number" id="value_a">
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label>Input B</label>
 <div>
 <input type="text" class="number" id="value_b">
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="form_c" style="display:none">
 <label>Input C</label>
 <div>
 <input type="text" class="number" id="value_c">
 </div>
 <i id="cancel_c_value">Close C</id>
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label>Total</label>
 <div>
 <input type="text" class="number" id="total" readonly>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how to choose the ID for the trigger? @CertainPerformace

Comment: You can pick any element which will result in the handler running. Since the listener is attached to `$("#value_a, #value_b, #value_c")`, any of those will do. You could also save the callback function in a separate variable, then pass it to the handler *and* call it manually at the end of the close handler.